# IE doesn't read Windows authentication after user in windows group change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

I have a following problem with ASP.NET MVC C# app. I use windows authentication, and everything works perfect except refreshing IsInRole after assigment / unassigment user to / from windows group. I have to restart my windows to read get proper data. In FF it works fine. My configuration: ASP.NET MVC, .NET 4.5.1, windows authentication, Windows 8.1 Pro, IIS 7.5- I do not use VisualStudio build in IIS. Any ideas?

Comment: in FF you have to log in every time I think - the difference is that IE/Chrome(?) will use the token you got when you logged into windows so this is to be expected (see here for example: https://www.ehow.com/how_7385911_update-windows-security-token-reboot.html) - this has nothing to do with your program - it's windows ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour.  The user has to log out and back in before any changes in group membership are processed.

(It doesn't happen in Firefox because there is no integrated authentication; the user is re-authenticated each time.  The downside to this is that it means that the user has to provide the username and password each time, or allow Firefox to remember it.)

Generally speaking, this shouldn't be a problem, because group membership is expected to change infrequently.  If you are using group membership in a way that requires it to be changed often, you should consider using an alternative mechanism, e.g., put the user roles in a database.